# What causes the "Press Shutter Release Button Again" error on a Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, error, shutter-release

I have a Nikon D40x that has been working fine for over 5 years now. It just recently quit on me with the error message "Press Shutter Release Button Again". I have cleaned and lubricated the red shutter wheel on the bottom of the camera and it will work for a few test shots then quit again. Please I need help!

I have read some articles that mention a mirror problem but I have no idea what to search for. If someone can provide a more specific article on mirror problems that could cause this that would be great! Or any other ideas!

Comment: Send it to Nikon for repair. The work that they do is excellent.

Comment: Yes, prices are reasonable too, but of course it will be as much as buying another second hand D40x

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem during a trip. I lubricated the red shutter wheel with WD40. You have to roll the wheel and try to use as little as possible WD40. Since then (4 years ago) my D40 is working perfect with hundreds of shots. Of course, there is a possibility that the above solution might not work.

Answer (score 1):

My Nikon camera would not start, or it would suddenly stop. In this case I finally found out that the battery connectors were losing contact with the battery from time to time. Pressing the battery door inwards would start the camera. So I inserted a folded paper between the battery door and the battery. This presses the contacts properly and the camera works fine now. My camera is 14 yrs old so the spring stiffness of the contacts may have been lost causing the issue. I had of course cleaned all contacts before I solved the problem this way. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).